My ST7735 TFT Display is showing stuff cursed
I am trying to display text on my display but it shows stuff very weirdly, it's hardly readable. I am using the Raspberry Pi Zero 2 W with the Raspberry Pi Os Lite 64 bit.
I have SPI activated.
This is how the Display is connected to the Pi:

GND → GND
VCC → 3.3V
SCK → Raspberry Pi GPIO11 (SCLK)
SDA → Raspberry Pi GPIO10 (MOSI)
RES → Raspberry Pi GPIO25
RS → Raspberry Pi GPIO24
CS → Raspberry Pi GPIO8
LEDA → 3.3V

Display: https://www.amazon.de/dp/B078JBBPXK?ref=ppx_yo2ov_dt_b_fed_asin_title&th=1
Image of what the Display shows: https://ibb.co/hH9jBXt
Python Code for the Display:
import st7735
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import time

disp = st7735.ST7735(
    port=0,
    cs=0,
    dc=24,
    rst=25,
    rotation=0,
    width=128,
    height=160,
    invert=False
)


WIDTH = disp.width
HEIGHT = disp.height

disp.begin()

image = Image.new('RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), (255, 0, 0))

text = "Hello"

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)

font = ImageFont.truetype('/home/lowfa/myproject/NewAmsterdam-Regular.ttf', 30)

draw.text((0,0), text, font=font)


disp.display(image)


Out of curiosity (it doesn't make sense though) have you tried swapping width and height values?

@JaromandaX I tried it. Now it looks even more cursed. (https://ibb.co/tY3fTYw)

If it is cursed you need the services of spiritual advisor.

Please check if you have enabled the SPI interface in your Raspberry Pi. After checking the interface, try to display a simple image or some basic shapes to make sure that the display itself is functioning properly. You can try this code:
import st7735
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import time

disp = st7735.ST7735(
    port=0,
    cs=0,
    dc=24,
    rst=25,
    rotation=0,
    width=128,
    height=160,
    invert=False
)

WIDTH = disp.width
HEIGHT = disp.height

disp.begin()

# Create a new image with red background
image = Image.new('RGB', (WIDTH, HEIGHT), (255, 0, 0))

draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
draw.rectangle((0, 0, WIDTH, HEIGHT), (0, 255, 0))  # Green rectangle

disp.display(image)


You can also test the TFT display on a different platform like Arduino or ESP8266. Here is a tutorial of  ST7735 TFT Display and ESP8266.
https://www.pcbway.com/project/shareproject/ESP8266_Nodemcu_ST7735_TFT_Display_based_Weather_Station_b91d78a4.html
